# Display modal box while servlet is processing

Tags: javascript, java, html, servlets

I am trying to show user a modal box in a java servlet with message - "Please wait while your request is processed". 
I know I can do a ajax call and handle the modal in the front end code. I am currently opening the servlet on click of a button by the user. Servlet takes around 2 minutes to process. Is there any way I can show processing  box when servlet starts executing and hide it once it ends?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that what you're trying to do is this

1. When users clicks button, show status modal popup, then launch request to servlet.
2. When servlet has finished processing, client receives a response. On receiving a successful response, hide status modal. If unsuccessful, show error in the modal

User clicks button
Modal pops up with message "servlet processing"
An Ajax request is then sent to the servlet
If response is valid, Modal message is " processing successful"

If response is invalid, Modal message is " error try again" or whatever way you would like to handle the scenario.

Note that because of how processing is done, the modal has to popup first before you send the request. The user doesn't know the order of events. To them, it will look like the modal popped up at the same time the request was sent.